# When starting Postgres docker image SQL from initdb.d is executed but db/schema/table are not created

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting postgresql 12.3 image via dokcer-compose
I extended the image to execute simple SQL (create schema, table) on start.
From the logs I can see that the SQL commands are executed but when I log to the DB the changes are missing.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres

ENV INITDB_DIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...
ENV POSTGRES_DB mydb

COPY initdb.d ${INITDB_DIR}
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    build: ./postgres
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:...}
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

create_schema.sql (located in ./postgres/initdb.d)

```
create schema "foo";
create table "foo"."message"(
  "id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "value" TEXT
);
alter table "foo"."message" add constraint "foo_message_pk" primary key("id");
```

And finally the logs produced when executing: docker-compose up --build postgres

```
postgres_1                | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1                | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1                | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1                | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1                | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1                | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1                | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_1                | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1                | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_1                | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1                | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres_1                | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres_1                | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1                | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1                | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_1                | waiting for server to start....2020-05-27 07:34:00.098 UTC [47] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.112 UTC [47] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.143 UTC [48] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-27 07:33:59 UTC
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.151 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1                |  done
postgres_1                | server started
postgres_1                | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_schema.sql
postgres_1                | CREATE SCHEMA
postgres_1                | CREATE TABLE
postgres_1                | ALTER TABLE
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | waiting for server to shut down....2020-05-27 07:34:00.588 UTC [47] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.593 UTC [47] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.595 UTC [47] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.595 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.643 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1                |  done
postgres_1                | server stopped
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1                |
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.708 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.709 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.709 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.719 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.744 UTC [74] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-05-27 07:34:00 UTC
postgres_1                | 2020-05-27 07:34:00.753 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

When I connect to the database only the default database (postgres) is present. i also tried the above without creating mydb database but still the schema or table were not present.